# Is it OK having several forEach?

Tags: javascript, arrays, performance, foreach

I'm looking for the best practice solution. I have a very nested object of data getting in the frontend to build forms. The instance of data:

```
forms: {
  form1: {
    title1: 'title1',
      fields: {
        field1: {
          label: 'field1 label',
            value: null,
            description: ''
        },             
      },
  },
  form2: {
      title2: 'title2',
      description: '',
          fields: [
            {
              title: 'title',
              subsections: [
                {
                  title: 'title',
                  options: [
                    {
                      id: 1,
                      label: '',
                      answer: '',
                      isSomething: false,
                      attachments: []
                    },
                    {
                      id: 2,
                      label: '',
                      answer: '',
                      isSomething: false,
                      attachments: []
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  title: 'title',
                  options: [
                    {
                      id: 3,
                      label: '',
                      answer: '',
                      isSomething: false,
                      attachments: []
                    },
                    {
                      id: 4,
                      label: '',
                      answer: '',
                      isSomething: false,
                      attachments: []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]

            },
            {
              title: 'title',
              subsections: [
                {
                  title: 'title',
                  options: [
                    {
                      id: 5,
                      label: '',
                      answer: '',
                      isSomething: false,
                      attachments: []
                    },
                    {
                      id: 6,
                      label: '',
                      answer: '',
                      isSomething: false,
                      attachments: []
                    }
                  ]
                },
                {
                  title: 'title',
                  options: [
                    {
                      id: 7,
                      label: '',
                      answer: '',
                      isSomething: false,
                      attachments: []
                    },
                    {
                      id: 8,
                      label: '',
                      answer: '',
                      isSomething: false,
                      attachments: []
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
    }
}
```

As you can see I have attachments, that's why I'm using dropzone (initializing onClick) for it. It's necessary to initialize plugin for each item.
I use several forEach functions to make it. Like that:

```
forms.form2.fields.forEach(function (i) {

  t.subsections.forEach(function (i2) {

    t2.options.forEach(function (i3) {

      var id = '#option-' + i3.id;

      //stuff here is not necessary

    });

  });

});
```

Is it OK for performance?
Is there any way to implement it better?

P.S. It would be nice if you downvote, please explain why. Thank you!

Comment: if it works and if the structure is not the same for every level, then it's fine. a different iteration style, like recursive has more overhead.

Comment: Unless you have literally thousands of lines of data, performance shouldn't be an issue. I suppose you could switch to `for` loops to gain more speed, but unless you *know* you have a problem with performance, `forEach` should be fine.

Comment: At a glance, 3-level-nested forEach looks like an adequate approach, dictated by your data structure. Can it be done better? Perhaps. Hard to tell without a deeper analysis.

Comment: Nesting foreach is not the best practice, you can use map() instead

Comment: If you elaborate on what `//stuff here is not necessary` is, there might be a better way

Comment: @dram I don't see it, can you elaborate?

Comment: @dram: using `map` for looping is an actual bad practice. forEach is fine (here).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a code review (and this thus too broad / opinion based). It could probably be adjusted to be on topic for [the code review stackexchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: forEach() is cca 70% slower than map()
https://jsperf.com/map-vs-foreach-speed-test
which should not be a problem in this particular case, so forEach() is fine here, but Id say for more complex scenarios is map() superior to nested forEach()